# Creating a QR-code containing a link in NodejS

Tags: html, node.js, qr-code

I'm working on a project right now, i need to create a qrcode that contains a specific information in NodeJS. I have started by creating the canvas in HTML, and take it in NodeJS

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```

And then in my NodeJS file, i'm launching my function

```
const fs = require('fs');
const qrcode = require('qrcode');

module.exports = {
  generateQr: function(link){
    var canvas = new qrcode(document.getElementById('canvas'));

    qrcode.toCanvas(canvas, link, function (error) {
    if (error) console.error(error)
    console.log('success!');
    });
  }
};
```

Unfortunately, i got the error :

`ReferenceError: document is not defined`

From the above code, does it look correct ? Does the Qrcode get the data i'm passing, and then what should i do so the QR-code appear in my HTML ?

Thank you for your help

Comment: `document` is a browser-specific global object, you can't access it in node

Comment: Try `const result = await qrcode.toDataURL('<your specific information>')` It should generate base-64 image of QR

Answer (score 0):

[document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document) is a browser-specific global object, you can't access it in node

In `node` environment, you could generate an image with QR code and use it.

Example:

Async/Await style:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const qrcode = require('qrcode');

module.exports = {
  generateQr: async link => {
    const qrCodeDataUrl = await qrcode.toDataURL(link);
    // ...
  }
};
```

Promise style:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const qrcode = require('qrcode');

module.exports = {
  generateQr: link => {
    qrcode.toDataURL(link)
       .then(data => {
          const qrCodeDataUrl = data;
          // ...
       })
       .catch(err => {
          console.error(error);
          // ...
       });
  }
};
```

Callback style:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const qrcode = require('qrcode');

module.exports = {
  generateQr: link => {
    qrcode.toDataURL(link, function(err, data) {
       if (error) console.error(error);
       const qrCodeDataUrl = data;
       // ...
    });
  }
};
```

To render it in an HTML-file you could use template-engine of your choice:

Example with [ejs](https://ejs.co/#install):

```
const ejs = require('ejs');

// In some route
const qrCodeDataUrl = await generateQr('some link');
const html = ejs.render('<img src="<%= qrCodeDataUrl %>" />', {qrCodeDataUrl});

res.header('Content-Type', 'text/html');
res.send(html);
// ...
```

> Note: It's a simplified example. Please check [ejs](https://ejs.co) docs for more details

Comment: Ok thank you, it worked but how do i print it out on my html file ?

Comment: If you need to do it server-side, you could embed it as an image (`<img src="..." />`) using template engine of your choice (ejs, handlebars, etc);

Comment: Do i add it in my nodejs file or in the html ? 
Or do i stock the value of the qr-code and send it to my html file through a "resp.render" ?

Thank you for your response

Comment: It's highly depending on your application logic

Comment: If you already have SSR set-up, you could embed `qrCodeDataUrl` into your template and use `res.render('...')` to render it and send to the client